# SSH Tunnel connect 2 Servers via third Server

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I have 3 Servers, **A** is a public accessable Server in the Internet.
**B** Hosts a Webservice I want to access.
**C** has access rights to connect to A and B.

Now i want that if a Client **D** tries to access a special Port on A that he gets forwarded to B.

### IP's and Ports

A:

- 1.0.0.1:22 SSHD Server
- 1.0.0.1:443 Public Port which i want to use

B:

- 1.0.0.2:23 SSHD Server
- 1.0.0.2:444 Webservice I want to access

C:

- 1.0.0.3

D:

- 1.0.0.4

### Diagram:

```
  +------------+        +------------+
  | Client (D) +--------> Public (A) |
  +------------+        +-----^------+
                              |
  +----------------+    +-----------+
  | Webservice (B) <----+ Proxy (C) |
  +----------------+    +-----------+
```

### Question:

What ssh tunnel Commands do i need to execute on **C** so that if i try to open 1.0.0.1:443 on **D** i get the service hosted on 1.0.0.2:444 ?

Comment: I think i got half of it working by creating an ssh Relay with the following command: ssh -R 443:1.0.0.2:444 user@1.0.0.1 -p 22 This way, any connection from A to localhost:443 will return 1.0.0.2:444. However It is not possible to access yet from Client D

Comment: What you search is something like SSH VPN https://www.startpage.com/do/search?query=ssh+vpn

Comment: You need to allow remote connects with the `-o GatewayPorts yes` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On C you can run

```
ssh -fNR 1.0.0.1:443:1.0.0.2:444 root@1.0.0.1
```

It will only work if you login as `root` user because `443` is a privileged port. Moreover it only works if `sshd` on A is configured with `GatewayPorts` set to `yes` or `clientspecified`. (The default is `no` and using `yes` cannot be recommended, so if you want to do it this way I recommend `clientspecified`).

Comment: You could avoid all the problems using `socat` and `sudo`. e.g: `ssh 1.0.0.1 "sudo -b  socat tcp-l:443,fork,reuseaddr tcp:1.0.0.2:444 2>/dev/null 2>&1"`.

Comment: @rudimeier You are assuming there is a route between A and B. The question sort of implies there isn't any such route.

Comment: Ah, ok. Anyways, in this case (and if C is reachable by A)  I would run one `socat` on A (forward A to C) and another `socat`  on C (forward C to B). The advantage is that it's more easy to start the tunnels onboot on A and C independently without any auto-ssh-login involved.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite how SSH tunnels work.You can get near to what you describe, but not exactly in the way you draw it up.

2 options are available to you:

> 1. use **L**ocal port forwarding
> 2. use **D**ynamic port forwarding

### 1) Local port forwarding

This requires you to change your approach: the tunnel needs to be opened from the client, from D in your diagram.
it is easy to achieve, on the client (D) just do a

```
ssh -L 443:1.0.0.2:444 user@1.0.0.3
```

of course that requires you to:

- have shell access or a putty client on D
- have a user on the proxy (C) that D can login to
- be able to connect from D to C via ssh
- have the X11Forwarding and AllowTcpForwarding set to yes in the server config on C

I will explain Dynamic port forwarding in a moment

Comment: Between D and A ist the Internet and between A and C is the Internet. Only B and C are in the same network. So i don't think i can do local port forwarding. I will take a look at dynamic port forwarding

Comment: local port forwarding would still work for you, if you can reach C from D, and C can reach B.  But you really need to be able to start the tunnel from a shell or a putty on D, the client. If you cannot do this, your only options is Dynamic port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

@kasperd mentioned that you can set GatewayPorts for the user to you don't have to use nginx. I leave the workaround here for others.

Add this to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Match User <username>
   GatewayPorts yes
```

### Original Answer:

I found a solution achieving this with ssh and nginx.
It is not perfect because i have to install a nginx server on A with a proxy.
I had to enable ssl and give this nginx instance a own ssl certificate.

So the Solution will look like this:
**C** will execute the following command to create a Relay between A and B:

```
ssh -R 445:1.0.0.2:444 user@1.0.0.1 -p 22
```

This will cause any input on Port 445 on 1.0.0.1 to be redirected to 1.0.0.2:444.
So a local user on **A** can now execute`wget https://localhost:445 --no-check-certificate` to get the index page of your webservice.
However it is not public available yet.
(in case you wonder: Port 445 is correct, i must use some unused port yet for the next part)

So i created a nginx server on **A** which will redirect any traffic from Port 443 to port 445. And used the following config:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        ssl on;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

        server_name proxy.<your-domain>.com;

        location / {
          proxy_pass        https://127.0.0.1:445;
          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        }
}
```

Now you can use your webbrowser (in incognito mode on Firefox to prevent issues with the certificate) to suft to https://proxy..com:443 and get the result from your Webservice.
The IP of proxy..com must be 1.0.0.1.

What i dislike here is that i have to create a new webserver which will create a new encrypted session instead of just redirecting the one of my webservice located on **B**.
However this is a good workaround till i find a better solution.